# Decode Registry Value stored in HKCU\...\Lock Screen\SlideshowDirectoryPath1

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am having trouble to decode the SlideshowDirectoryPath1 in my local Windows 10 computer by C++ program. I read this link:

"https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edc2e1de-c7c6-4bef-becb-cf4924165551/decode-encrypted-path-from-slideshowdirectorypath1?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues"

It seems that the value is Base64 encoded. So I decoded it and then I passed the decoded result to SHGetPathFromIDList. After I successfully decoded the value (see my attached test program), the code failed in the call "SHGetPathFromIDList". The program always prints "Error when converting the path". And I have no clue on what was going wrong. I have tried my program in more than one computer.

Anyone could shed me some lights?

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console
// application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <WinCrypt.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Testing" << endl;  

  CRegKey regKey;
  LSTATUS status;
  TCHAR path[2000] = _T("");
  ULONG size = 2000;

  if (ERROR_SUCCESS !=
          (status = regKey.Open(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Wi")
                                                   _T("ndows\\CurrentVersion\\")
                                                   _T("Lock Screen"))) ||
      ERROR_SUCCESS != (status = regKey.QueryStringValue(
                            _T("SlideshowDirectoryPath1"),
                            reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(path), &size))) {
    regKey.Close();
    cerr << "Error in getting registry SlideshowDirectoryPath1, " << status
         << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  cout << size << endl;
  wcout << path << endl;

  DWORD outSize;
  status = CryptStringToBinary(path, _tcslen(path), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL,
                               &outSize, NULL, NULL);

  if (status == 0) {
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    cerr << "Error in converting base 64 step 1, " << dw << endl;
    return 1;
  }  
  ITEMIDLIST item;

  status = CryptStringToBinary(path, _tcslen(path), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
                               (BYTE *)&item, &outSize, NULL, NULL);

  if (status == 0) {
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    cerr << "Error in converting base 64 step 2, " << dw << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  cout << "Getting Path value, input size:" << outSize << endl;

  TCHAR *result = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];

  if (!SHGetPathFromIDList(&item, result)) {
    cerr << "Error when converting the path" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  wcout << result << endl;

  regKey.Close();

  delete result;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use  CryptBinaryToString instead of  CryptStringToBinary ?

Comment: em...When I tried to decode the base64 value stored in registry back to the ITEMIDLIST object, I think I should use the String->Binary, right?

Comment: I don't know ! But in your code you get the data from the registry and that data is encrypted (binary ?) so it would make sense to me to decrypt it (string ?). You could try it ! If it works you've got your answer !

Comment: The so-called pidl doesn't look like a pidl (testing on my Windows 10 box) which would explain why it doesn't work. Do you have an example of your base64 input string?

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for helping me on this. The base64 string in my computer is obtained by Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen\SlideshowDirectoryPath1. This value is set by Windows 10 after you configure "Lock Screen"->"Choose albums for your slideshow" in Settings. The Lock Screen's "Background" value has to be "Slideshow". I think that base64 string is different for each computer so I think it wouldn't help if I copy mine to you.